# How do I show results of a form in current page using php?

Tags: php, html, forms

I tried to put php and the `form` in the same file and form `action="currentpage.php"`.
The problem is, if form `action` is the current page, during the initial opening of this page, the `$get` or `$post` methods in php cannot get any values from input areas of the `form` because the `form` hasn't been submitted. And I will get a lot of undefined error.

What should I do?

If I have to separate `form` and php scripts into two files, do I have to copy all other codes in current page to the new page in order to keep other part of the page unchanged? Prefer a method not to do so!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a submit button. You will also need to post to the same page

Once you clicked the submit button the page will reload. You will need to add an if statement to see if the submit button was clicked otherwise you will get errors

```
If (isset ($_POST ['submit'])) {
}
```

Your form should start as follows

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above ^ your form should include a button with the id and name as 'submit'at the end of your form such as:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
```

then in your php include:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 }
```

this means the submit button will trigger you php code and make your form do what you want it to do